# Is there a way to use group to select the id's of the grouped records in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Purchase.all.group( :user_id ).sum( :price )
```

This returns

```
[{ 1 : 234 }, { 2 : 345 }, ...
```

Is it possible to pull the `Purchase`  ids?

For example, suppose the first group returned:

```
{ user_id : 1, price : 234, ids : [3,6,9] }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using postgresql, you can use `array_agg`:

```
Purchase.select('user_id, sum(price) as price, array_agg(id) as ids').group('user_id')
```

Comment: This looks good according to the PostgreSQL docs, but it does not return an `ids` key for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yeah it works for me. Try it in your console with a  `to_json` call

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: One limitation I found is that the names must match. To get the array of prices: `AS price` works, but `AS prices` does not.

Comment: That is the issue for me. It works with `AS id`, but not `AS ids`. Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres 9.3.5 and Rails 4.1.7. It should work but it won't show on the return. For instance, when you do the call above, your response should be `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Purchase id: nil, price: 200>, ...]>`. The `ids` won't show up since the `Purchase` model does not have an `ids` column. But each object in the relation will have the `ids` key. So when you do `Purchase.select('user_id, sum(price) as price, array_agg(id) as ids').group('user_id').order(:user_id).first.ids`, this should return the `ids` array

Comment: That's funny. I am using postgres 9.3.5 and Active Record 4.1.7. It's a Rack app.

Comment: You're right. The ids are not in the AR relation. However, they are there when accessed with `.ids`. How did you find that out? Why does it work that way?

Comment: I do not have any documentation to back this up, but I think it does not show up because `ids` is not a column in the specified model. For me, when I want to see all the selected keys from the query (or when running tests), I usually run `to_json` as suggested in my first comment (i.e. `Purchase.select('user_id, sum(price) as price, array_agg(id) as ids').group('user_id').to_json`).

Comment: @AbM can you update your answer to include your notes in this last comment? This was what solved it for me but had to dig down in the comments here to find it.